# How to attach text using AWK

Tags: database, linux, unix, awk, db2

Sorry if i may have missed this out while searching on SO. 
I have a text file with the following structure

```
AAAA21346A  
AAAA21346A  
AAAA21346A  
AAAA21346A 
.  
.  
.
```

till more than 5 lakhs records (half a million records).

I want to attach ^N^1 in front of every row using `awk`. How can it be done?

*Update:*

My output has to look like this:

```
AAAA21346A^N^1
AAAA21346A^N^1
AAAA21346A^N^1
AAAA21346A^N^1
```

and so on till EOF. There has to be a line break after every record.

***some more explanation*************
I am using db2 and linux and hence i thought of Awk. What i am trying to do is, i need to insert the data into table with 3 columns using "load from" command in db2 and using a ^ as delimiter. But Since the text file contains only one column and i want to attach ^N^1 to make it into 3 column. i hope yall understand now.

Comment: It's not very clear.  Can you show us a sample of the output you'd like to see?  Also, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: sorry. My output has to look like this "AAAA21346A"^N^1  "AAAA21346A"^N^1  "AAAA21346A"^N^1  "AAAA21346A"^N^1  and so on till EOF. line break has too be there after every 1

Comment: I havent tried anything uptill now. what i have been doing recently was import all the rows in excel and attach the required thing and then export using Csv using ^ delimited file. This was working wonderfully uptill 100 records...but hell no for 5 lacs which willl increase till 50 lacs in a few days..

Comment: Please edit your question (you can!) rather than putting material in a comment.  All else apart, you can format the material in the question.  Isn't it 'lakh' for 100,000?

Comment: What's a "lac"?   Also, what problem are you trying to solve?  Not sure why you hit on awk as the solution here.

Comment: You can try this: `sed 's/$/^N^1/' input.txt`

Answer (score 2):

What you want appears to be very easy:

```
awk '{print $0 "^N^1"}' data_file
```

The only problem with adding thread IDs is deciding on the algorithm for doing so.  For example, alternating is very easy too:

```
awk '{printf "%s^N^%d\n", $0, (NF % 2) + 1}' data_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more ways to do it using AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = "^N^1\n"} 1' inputfile
```

or, more explicitly:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS = "^N^1\n"} {print}' inputfile
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "^"} {$2 = "N"; $3 = 1}1' inputfile
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "^"} {$2 = "N"; $3 = 1; print}' inputfile
```

Comment: Thank you too!...i am completely new to awk and this really helped me.

Comment: @koderhash - don't forget to click the checkmark on the answer that helped you the most!